# Trying to left join to bring together several tables to show latest maintenance work ticket completed date

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server tables I am dealing with:

property
unit
tenant
work orders

I have a query that shows all, essentially, apartment units that are "unrented" and who is the last person that lived in the apartment.  This query works like a charm.

```
select
p.scode, 
p.saddr1, 
u.scode as 'Unit Number', 
u.sstatus, 
convert(varchar, u.dtvacant, 101) as 'Date Vacant', 
convert(varchar, u.dtavailable, 101) as 'Date Available',
convert(varchar, u.dtready, 101) as 'Date Ready',
datediff(day, u.dtvacant, getdate()) as 'Days Vacant',
u.srent, 
case when cast(u.irentready as varchar) = '1' then 'Yes'
     when cast(u.irentready as varchar) = '0' then 'No'
end,
t.sfirstname,
t.slastname,
case when cast(t.istatus as varchar) = 1 then 'Past tenant/Moved Out'
     when cast(t.istatus as varchar) = 4 then 'Still in Unit/Gave Notice'
end,
t.dtmoveout,
t.dtmovein
from property p
left join unit u on p.hMy = u.hproperty
left join tenant t on u.scode = t.sunitcode
and exists (select 1
            from tenant t1
            where t.sunitcode = t1.sunitcode 
            having max(t1.dtmoveout) = t.dtmoveout)
where 1=1
and u.sstatus like '%Unrented%'
and p.binactive = 0
and t.istatus != 0
order by p.scode, u.scode
```

I need to find the last or latest maintenance work ticket that is category "Unit Turnover," if there is a unit turn ticket for that unit, that was "completed" for the "unrented" unit to so show the date that the unit was turned and is ready for someone to move into.

My problem is trying to join the work order table, which is principally driven by the property table as you do not need a unit to enter a work ticket.  Obviously, if there is a unit that needs work, you enter that unit # so the tech knows where to go to do the work etc.

This query works and shows tix that are category unit turnover called in since 4/1/23.  I can get the date completed from this table, not an issue, how do I link this scenario to the above query???

```
select u.scode, u.srent, p.saddr1, wo.sbriefdesc, p.scode, wo.dtcall
from mm2wo wo
left join property p on wo.hproperty = p.hmy
left join (select top 1 * from unit) u on p.hmy = u.hproperty
where 
wo.dtcall > '2023-04-01'
and wo.scategory = 'Unit Turnover'
```

I tried below but I am not sure how to get what I want

```
select top 100
p.scode, 
p.saddr1, 
u.scode as 'Unit Number', 
u.sstatus, 
convert(varchar, u.dtvacant, 101) as 'Date Vacant', 
convert(varchar, u.dtavailable, 101) as 'Date Available',
convert(varchar, u.dtready, 101) as 'Date Ready',
datediff(day, u.dtvacant, getdate()) as 'Days Vacant',
u.srent, 
case when cast(u.irentready as varchar) = '1' then 'Yes'
     when cast(u.irentready as varchar) = '0' then 'No'
end,
t.sfirstname,
t.slastname,
case when cast(t.istatus as varchar) = 1 then 'Past tenant/Moved Out'
     when cast(t.istatus as varchar) = 4 then 'Still in Unit/Gave Notice'
end,
t.dtmoveout,
t.dtmovein
from property p

left join unit u on p.hMy = u.hproperty
left join tenant t on u.scode = t.sunitcode
and exists (select 1
            from tenant t1
            where t.sunitcode = t1.sunitcode 
            having max(t1.dtmoveout) = t.dtmoveout)
/* left join mm2wo wo on p.hmy = wo.hproperty
and exists (
  select 1
            from mm2wo wo1
            where wo.hproperty = wo1.hproperty 
            having max(wo1.dtwcompl) = wo.dtwcompl
  ) */
where 1=1
and u.sstatus like '%Unrented%'
and p.binactive = 0
and t.istatus != 0
order by p.scode, u.scode
```

The query does not finish.

Property - JBJ Soul Homes
unit - 201
status - vacan unrented ready
date available - 6/2/2023 <<<<<<<< this is the work ticket unit turn completed date
days vacant - 6
name - Tony Mamone <<<< last person who lived in the apt

Answer (score 0):

Check the below query that connects to the mm2wo database and returns the most recent completed work order for each unit's turnover category. row_number() method is to sort the work orders by completion date, and most recent work orders are selected for each unit.

```
select 
  p.scode, 
  p.saddr1, 
  u.scode as 'Unit Number', 
  u.sstatus, 
  convert(varchar, u.dtvacant, 101) as 'Date Vacant', 
  convert(varchar, u.dtavailable, 101) as 'Date Available',
  convert(varchar, u.dtready, 101) as 'Date Ready',
  datediff(day, u.dtvacant, getdate()) as 'Days Vacant',
  u.srent, 
  case when cast(u.irentready as varchar) = '1' then 'Yes'
       when cast(u.irentready as varchar) = '0' then 'No'
  end,
  t.sfirstname,
  t.slastname,
  case when cast(t.istatus as varchar) = 1 then 'Past tenant/Moved Out'
       when cast(t.istatus as varchar) = 4 then 'Still in Unit/Gave Notice'
  end,
  t.dtmoveout,
  t.dtmovein,
  convert(varchar, wo.dtwcompl, 101) as 'Turnover Completed Date'
from property p
left join unit u on p.hMy = u.hproperty
left join (
  select 
    *,
    row_number() over (partition by sunitcode order by dtwcompl desc) as rn
  from mm2wo
  where scategory = 'Unit Turnover' and dtwcompl > '2023-04-01'
  ) wo on u.scode = wo.sunitcode and wo.rn = 1
left join tenant t on u.scode = t.sunitcode
and exists (
  select 1
  from tenant t1
  where t.sunitcode = t1.sunitcode 
  having max(t1.dtmoveout) = t.dtmoveout
)
where 
  u.sstatus like '%Unrented%' 
  and p.binactive = 0 
  and t.istatus != 0
order by p.scode, u.scode
```